# Why my tabs (i.e HOME, ABOUT ME..) doesn't show the corresponding paragraph or section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Right now my navigation tabs are only clickable. I did it by using "anchor() tag". But as soon as I click it, it doesn't show the corresponding paragraph (which I already stored in my HTML file). Basically I haven't added any functionality to happen something after clicking the tab. And I don't know how to do that and which one is better (comparing with jquery and javascript).

This is my code:

.PHP file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Fatah's Homepage</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.1.8.14.custom.css">

<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<header id="top_header" >
<h1>Welcome to my world!</h1>

</header>
<!--This div wrapps all the tabs and corresponding section/paragraphs-->
<div id="giant_wrapper">
<div id="top_menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#who_im">WHO I'M</a></li>
<li><a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a></li>
<li><a href="#diary">MY DIARY</a></li>
<li><a href="#blog">FATAH'S BLOG</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">CONTACT ME</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="new_div">
<section id="main_section">
<!--This div section is for main contaents for my website. All the correcponding 
text and paragraph will be added here-->

<div id="all_contents">

<div id="home_contents">
<p> It's home.</p>
</div>

<div id="who_im_contents">
<p> It's who I'm.</p>
</div>

<div id="gallery_contents">
<p> It's Gallery.</p>
</div>

<div id="diary_contents">
<p> It's diary.</p>
</div>

<div id="blog_contents">
<p> It's my blog.</p>
</div>

<div id="contact_contents">
<p> contact info.</p>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
<footer id="the_footer">
Developed by Jabir Al Fatah 2014
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

.CSS file:

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;

}
h1{
font:bold 20px Tahoma;

}
h2{
font:bold 14px Tahoma;

}
header,section,footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
display:block;
}
body{
width:100%;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
}
#wrapper{
max-width:1000px;
margin:20px auto;
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
-webkit-box-flex:1;

}
#top_header{
background:green;
border:3px solid orange;
padding:20px;
text-align:center;
}
#top_menu{

background:white;
color:black;
border:3px solid red;
padding:4px;
text-align:center;
}
#top_menu li{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
padding:5px;
font:bold 14px Tahoma;
}
#new_div{
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
}
#main_section{

border:1px solid blue;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
margin:20px;
padding:20px;
}
#the_footer{
text-align:center;
padding:20px;
border-top: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting? That on click of the `a` you will jump down to the right content? Your `href="#.."` should match the `id="..."`

Comment: Put your code into a JS fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) and put the link in your question, so we can see it happening.

Comment: Showing something when something else is clicked is pretty trivial, and search engines abound with guides. You really should do some research before asking Stackoverflow.

Comment: Please check given answer it will help you to make tabs

Comment: John, check my jsfiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/AE7h2/2/

Comment: @JabirALFatah is it working now?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check below code it will work for you

```
$('ul > li > a').click(function () {
        $('#all_contents >div').hide();
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.attr('href');
        $(target).show();
        return false;
    });
```

Please see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AE7h2/2/)

Comment: Yogesh Sharma, what strange! making change with your code works on JSfiddle fine, but not in my computer. look it here http://jsfiddle.net/AE7h2/2/

Comment: Please check your console is there any error in console

Comment: @JabirALFatah aah actually I have updated HTML as well please see I have updated all divs ID with similar that href

Comment: i also did the same thing, i updated all divs id as u did. how to check error in console?

Comment: Which browser you are using? simply press F12 key it will open window on bottom and then you will see in that window there is consol tab

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>    isn't it how to add the java script file with main file?

Comment: oh it says: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Ok got it fist you need to add <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> this o top just under css link then it will work

Comment: I think you got my point let me know it's a simple problem we can solve this easily

Comment: @JabirALFatah First you need to add jQuery reference which I have given in my previous comment and then add your all script under that link then it will work

Comment: No, look, I copied and pasted my complete project here http://jsfiddle.net/jabirfatah91/DAU46/               it works here, but not in my computer.

Comment: @JabirALFatah Can you please send me your HTML page so I can look into that why it's not working complete HTML page as it is

Comment: This is my email id yyogesh1990@gmail.com, If you can send me complete HTML page then I can see why it's not working on your system

Comment: I did it check ur mail

Comment: Hey please replace Jquery reference with this "<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>"  I have sent you a HTML page as well on your email only update is Jquery Reference

Comment: @JabirALFatah Please check your email now, I have sent you another HTML file and I hope it will work now :)

Comment: it makes a complete sense now. I got rid off the battle. the thing is working nice now. thanks to Yogesh brother.

Answer (score 1):

your values in `href`  and `id` of divs are different ,that is the problem ,please match `div` id to navigations
ex:

```
<a href="#home_contents">Home</a>

<div id="home_contents">
<p> It's home.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually setting up is an in-page nav bar. If you change the links to match the actual ids then when you click the link the browser will scroll to the associated div.

In other words you need to either remove _contents from all your anchors or add _contents to all the links in top_menu, in order to have anything happen.